# What is a mapping type for Object[] from java to c++ in calling function?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

What is a mapping type for `Object[]` from Java to C++ when calling Java function from C++? The Java function has parameter **`Object[]`**.

I know for string it's `java/lang/String;` but for `Object[]` `(jobjectarray)` cannot find.

Comment: It's `jobjectArray`, not `jobjectarray`.  Are you using `javah` to generate your native header file?

Answer (score 0):

It's `[Ljava/lang/Object;`. The `[` denotes an array of the following type.